# Java Spring - IllegalStateException when retrieving data from jsp form

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

I have a pretty nasty and frustrating problem with a Maven Web Application, holding me back for some time.
Apparently, from my previous google searches, this is a common Spring MVC error, but i am not able to find the solution i need among the ones offered on the internet so far. Note that i am a beginner in Spring and in MVC concepts in general.

I have a web application which is supposed to manage a building administration (inhabitants, rent calculations, etc). I use Spring MVC, Hibernate, Java 1.8, Tomcat 8 server container, and SQL Server 2014. 
Firstly, this is my POJO for the bulding residents, a type called Inhabitant:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "INHABITANT")
public class Inhabitant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "APARTAMENT_NUMBER")
    private String apartamentNumber;

    @Column(name = "APARTAMENT_OWNER")
    private String apartamentOwner;

    @Column(name = "TELEPHONE_NUMBER")
    private String telephoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL_ADDRESS")
    private String emailAddress;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getApartamentNumber() {
        return apartamentNumber;
    }

    public void setApartamentNumber(String apartamentNumber) {
        this.apartamentNumber = apartamentNumber;
    }

    public String getApartamentOwner() {
        return apartamentOwner;
    }

    public void setApartamentOwner(String apartamentOwner) {
        this.apartamentOwner = apartamentOwner;
    }

    public String getTelephoneNumber() {
        return telephoneNumber;
    }

    public void setTelephoneNumber(String telephoneNumber) {
        this.telephoneNumber = telephoneNumber;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }
}
```

This is my dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="laura.bachelordegree.controller" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"> <!-- xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
        version="3.1" -->
    <display-name>BuildingAdministration</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is my jsp registration form, which should map to the Inhabitant object:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Registration</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="login/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="login/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 

<!-- Registration form - START -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <%--  <form role="form"> --%>
        <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="inhabitant" role="form" action="BuildingAdministration/src/main/webapp/login/result">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="well well-sm"><strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>Required Field</strong></div>
               <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputFirstName">Enter First Name</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <form:input path="firstName" type="text" cssClass="form-control" id="InputFirstName" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputLastName">Enter Last Name</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <form:input path="lastName" type="text" cssClass="form-control" id="InputLastName" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputApartmentNumber">Enter Apartment Number</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <form:input path="apartmentNumber" type="text" cssClass="form-control" id="InputApartmentNumber" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputApartmentOwner">Enter Apartment Owner</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <form:input path="apartmentOwner" type="text" cssClass="form-control" id="InputApartmentOwner" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputTelephoneNumber">Enter Telephone Number</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <form:input path="telephoneNumber" type="text" cssClass="form-control" id="InputTelephoneNumber" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputEmail">Enter Email</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <form:input path="emailAddress" type="email" cssClass="form-control" id="InputEmailFirst" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputEmail">Confirm Email</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <form:input path="emailAddress" type="email" cssClass="form-control" id="InputEmailSecond" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">
            </div>
          </form:form>
        <%-- </form> --%>
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-push-1">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    <strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Success! Message sent.</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span><strong> Error! Please check all page inputs.</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Registration form - END -->

</body>
</html>
```

And finally, the controller class, which should effectively map the data from the jsp form with the java entity, Inhabitant:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loadInhabitant(@ModelAttribute("inhabitant")Inhabitant inhabitant, 
           ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("firstName", inhabitant.getFirstName());
      model.addAttribute("lastName", inhabitant.getLastName());
      model.addAttribute("apartmentNumber", inhabitant.getApartamentNumber());
      model.addAttribute("apartmentOwner", inhabitant.getApartamentOwner());
      model.addAttribute("apartmentNumber", inhabitant.getApartamentNumber());
      model.addAttribute("telephoneNumber", inhabitant.getTelephoneNumber());
      model.addAttribute("emailAddress", inhabitant.getEmailAddress());
    return "result";
}
```

Now, this is the error i get whenever i try to run my application on the server:

message java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'inhabitant' available as request attribute

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

> exception org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
>   target object for bean name 'inhabitant' available as request
>   attribute
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:555)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:471)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
> root cause java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor
>   plain target object for bean name 'inhabitant' available as request
>   attribute
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:144)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:117)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
>     org.apache.jsp.login.index_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(index_jsp.java:322)
>     org.apache.jsp.login.index_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(index_jsp.java:216)
>     org.apache.jsp.login.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:148)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

I have tried a thousand things, but i just can't get it to work. So, please, can someone point out what i'm doing wrong? How can i correctly build the java object based on the information from the jsp form?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems you need to understand more about spring mvc.

**You are mapping your form request to a view.** you must map your form request to a controller method not a view, your form should look like this :

```
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/inhabitant/create" method="post" modelAttribute="inhabitant" >
   ....
   // have a look at spring form validation 
   // have a look at spring form elements eg. how error messages are displayed
</form:form>
```

**You need two methods in controller to create and save inhabitant** one for showing a form and another for saving form datas into database. Now your controller should look like this :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/inhabitant")
public class PostController {

@Autowired
private InhabitantService inhabitantService;

//Method that displays the form page
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String createForm(Model model ) {

    model.addAttribute("inhabitant", new Inhabitant()); // identifier should be same as modelattribute in your form "inhabitant"
    return "formpage"; // your form page name

}

// Method which will have the submitted data
// Validation is also done in this method
@RequestMapping(value="/create", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveForm( @ModelAttribute("inhabitant") @Valid Inhabitant inhabitant, //@valid is used for validation use it If you are doing validation
        BindingResult result // use only if you are doing validation)
{
       // use only If you are doing validation
       // If validation fails users must return to the same form view
       if (result.hasErrors()){
           return "formpage";
       }

       //and save the submitted form data
       inahabitantService.saveInhabitant(inhabitant);
enter code here
       return "success"; // success.jsp is a success page that you will see after creating a inhabitant
}
```

**Do not use '/login' as a url patern in your web.xml** Just dont do it.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern> //Just Use '/' instead of '/login'
</servlet-mapping>
```

**I doubt that you have configured hibernate properly** Post your hibernateConfiguration.xml file and persistence.xml file.

**You must learn and understand these:** Just take your time.

- Spring Model Controller View and how does it really work
- Spring Form elements, Spring Form Validation
- Jpa / hibernate basics / association in hibernate
- Jsp taglibs / JSP inside Jsp / Apache Tiles

Answer (score -1):

Don't do that

```
  model.addAttribute("firstName", inhabitant.getFirstName());
  model.addAttribute("lastName", inhabitant.getLastName());
  model.addAttribute("apartmentNumber", inhabitant.getApartamentNumber());
  model.addAttribute("apartmentOwner", inhabitant.getApartamentOwner());
  model.addAttribute("apartmentNumber", inhabitant.getApartamentNumber());
  model.addAttribute("telephoneNumber", inhabitant.getTelephoneNumber());
  model.addAttribute("emailAddress", inhabitant.getEmailAddress());
```

Do this instead

```
model.addAttribute("inhabitant", inhabitant);
```

Comment: I have tried that too, still i get the same error. Is there something wrong with the jsp file maybe?

Comment: If it helps, i get the same error even if i comment out the controller method. That's why i guess there's something wrong with the jsp.